# Exception Error must be type IListSource, IEnumerable or IDataSource. Gridview

Tags: asp.net, ado.net

I get a catch exp as Exception Error in which says, data source is an invalid type, it must either be of the type IListSource, IEnumerable or IDataSource.

This error comes when I try to add a new record to a database through a gridview, so I get the data from database nicely into this gridview, therefore I do not understand that I get a catch exp as exception when the database is not unavailable.
The @thesli_number  OleDbType.VarChar  Value = thenumber  is type of number in the db.

```
 'Add new record to DB
Protected Sub AddNewTask(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim thecat As String = DirectCast(GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txttestcat"), TextBox).Text
    Dim theinfo As String = DirectCast(GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txttestinfo"), TextBox).Text
    Dim thenumber As String = DirectCast(GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txttestnumber"), TextBox).Text

    Dim strSQL As String = ""
    strSQL = "" & _
    "INSERT INTO [TableTest] " & _
    "([test_cat], [test_info], [test_number])" & _
    "VALUES (@thesli_cat, @thesli_info, @thesli_number)"

    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MyConnStr").ConnectionString)
        Try
            conn.Open()
            Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(strSQL, conn)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@thesli_cat", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = thecat
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@thesli_info", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = theinfo
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@thesli_number", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = thenumber
            GridView1.DataSource = cmd
            GridView1.DataBind()
            'MsgBox("Row(s) Added !! ")
        Catch exp As OleDbException
            If True Then
                MsgBox("Error trying to add current record. " & vbCrLf & "Error: " & exp.Message & "Database Error", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
            End If
        Catch exp As Exception
            If True Then
                MsgBox("Error the Database can be unavailable atm. " & vbCrLf & "Error: " & exp.Message & "Database Error", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, MsgBoxStyle.Information)
            End If
        End Try
    End Using
End Sub
```

EDIT................EDIT.................EDIT...................EDIT

Ok i can now add data to the gridview, i can delete a record and i can add a new record.
But i cant get the update event to work, can u see whats wrong in this new code !?

```
    'Update record
Protected Sub UpdateTask(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewUpdateEventArgs)
    Dim theid = Convert.ToInt32(DirectCast(GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("lbltestid"), Label).Text)
    Dim thecat As String = DirectCast(GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("lbltestcat"), Label).Text
    Dim theinfo As String = DirectCast(GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("lbltestinfo"), Label).Text
    Dim thenumber As String = DirectCast(GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("lbltestnumber"), Label).Text

    Dim strSQL As String = ""
    strSQL = "" & _
    "UPDATE [TableTest] " & _
    "SET [test_cat] = @thesli_cat, [test_info] = @thesli_info, [test_number] = @thesli_number " & _
    "WHERE [test_id] = @thesli_id"

    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MyConnStr").ConnectionString)
        Try
            conn.Open()
            Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(strSQL, conn)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@thesli_id", OleDbType.Integer).Value = theid
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@thesli_cat", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = thecat
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@thesli_info", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = theinfo
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@thesli_number", OleDbType.Integer).Value = thenumber
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            'MsgBox("Row(s) Updated !! ")
            GridView1.EditIndex = -1
            GetRecords()
        Catch exp As OleDbException
            If True Then
                MsgBox("Error trying to add current record. " & vbCrLf & "Error: " & exp.Message & "Database Error", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
            End If
        Catch exp As Exception
            If True Then
                MsgBox("Error the Database can be unavailable atm. " & vbCrLf & "Error: " & exp.Message & "Database Error", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, MsgBoxStyle.Information)
            End If
        End Try
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: You cannot assign `cmd` in your example to `GridView1.DataSource`.

Comment: why not !? its from this tutorial... http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/GridView---Add-Edit-Update-Delete-and-Paging-the-AJAX-way.aspx

Comment: That example does not directly assign an `OleDbCommadn` to the DataSource, because it can't. If you look at the example the author passes the `cmd` variable to the `GetData` function `GetData(cmd)`, which more than likely executes the stored procedure and returns a DataSource supported type (e.g. `IListSource`, `IEnumerable` or `IDataSource`.

Comment: Hi Sam. ok sound right. can u plz. see/read the edit in main thread !?

Comment: Please ask a new question for your edit, since it actually is a whole new question. It's also helpful if you include the errors you encounter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the answer to your original question was answered in my comment above (posted below here in quotes), then you should mark this question as answered, then post an entirely new question so you get more accurate responses. This question no longer applies to your actual problem.

My answer which, in your comment, solved your original question:

> That example (referring to the link in your comment above) does not directly assign an 
>   *OleDbCommand* to the DataSource, because it
>   can't. If you look at the example the author passes the cmd variable
>   to the GetData function GetData(cmd), which more than likely executes
>   the stored procedure and returns a DataSource supported type (e.g.
>   IListSource, IEnumerable or IDataSource).